# TypeScript: Define type as any of interface keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am developing a React/TypeScript project and I am facing the following situation:

I have an interface Actions which has many keys.

`interface Actions {`
`toggle: {`
`type: 'toggle',`
`},`
`alert: {`
`type: 'alert',`
`payload: string`
`}`
}`

I want to define a type Action which shall assume any of Actions subtypes and only those.

How can that be done?

Comment: If the actions are defined in the `Actions` interface you could use `type Action = Actions[keyof Actions]`